# how to match "test\w*" but not "tester" with a single regex expression

Tags: c#, regex

Say I have the following string:

```
test tester tested testing
```

I wish to match every word that begins with `test`, but not the word `tester`. The pattern `test\w*` does most of the job, but I have no idea how to add that `tester` should not be matched. A working pattern should give 3 matches on the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for your purposes?

```
test(?!er).*
```

Comment: That matches the whole string, `test(?!er)\w*` works however.